# Looking for Android design tool on Macbook

Tags: android

I'm looking for a free tool on Macbook for Android GUI design. I just want to easily draw GUI prototype for review purpose with internal team and customer. Could anybody recommend me a tool? If no such recommendation on Macbook, Windows based tool is acceptable too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried a couple but the one I liked the most was [Pencil](http://pencil.evolus.vn/), available as standalone application and as a firefox plugin. I searched a time ago, so chances are that you could find something better, but it's worthy to give it a try.